# How to change the sender / from field using Postfix as SMTP relay server to relay to MSO365 mailbox

Tags: postfix, smtp, microsoft-office-365

My company have set up an Ubuntu 22.04 Server to act as an SMTP relay server to relay messages to our Exchange online mail server.

A user account user@company.com has been setup on the Exchange to be used for relaying. We have multiple multifunction printers and webservers that sends messages / alerts using Postfix on the Ubuntu server to send mail.

Postfix is configured on the Ubuntu server and is working.
The problem is when messages / alerts are sent from the webservers or printers, it is delivered successfully but the sender / from field is always using user@company.com.

What we want is for the sender / from field to be changed to reflect who or what application that sent the message. We have tried using `header_checks`, `sender_canonical_maps`, etc. without any success.

Ideally the sender / from field needs to be changed to reflect who or which application  sent the message.

```
postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 3.6
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, echo.buckingham.ac.uk, localhost.buckingham.ac.uk, , localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.100.0.4, 10.100.0.84, 10.100.1.204, 10.100.0.5
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = [smtp.office365.com]:587
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_by_sender
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/controlled_envelope_senders
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/privat
```

Comment: sender_canonical_maps is the way to go i think , what exactly didn't worked? How did you configure it? A side note why did specify individual host addresses in the mynetworks?

Comment: Instead of using one account in exchange I would use multiple accounts, also for security reasons, if the main relay account is compromised, all notifications can be gone, with multiple accounts you are able to contain. Or create contacts/aliases in Exhange which forward to main account. That's also easier to troubleshoot, when a system is not sending notifications you can more easily pinpoint then when using one account which catches all

Answer (score 1):

(this should probably be a comment but its bit long).

> A user account user@company.com has been setup on the Exchange to be used for relaying....but the sender / from field is always using user@company.com

This is [how Exchange Online works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365):

> The email address of the account that's used to authenticate with Microsoft 365 or Office 365 will appear as the sender of messages from the device or application.

The simplest solution here is to configure a new domain in DNS and use that as the (postfix) origin rather than relaying.

A workaround would be to use RFC 5233 sub-addressing (so your emails could come from e.g. user+211hplaser@example.com with the user:example.com account).

You could fudge the header FROM to be different from the envelope FROM but thats going to cause more issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would could create a catch all for a seperate domain or something like that, which forwards everything to m365. You can use virtual alias maps for that. Then you can use any email address in your devices.

`virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual`

*/etc/postfix/virtual file*

```
@yourdomain.com   catchall@example.com
```

`sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`

`sudo systemctl reload postfix`

Comment: Is this problem solvable? I have tried the above using virtual_alias_maps but still doesn't work. Is my question / problem not clear enough? I reading everywhere that one can use

Comment: header_checks, sender_canonical_maps and what have you to resolve this problem. I have tried everything without any success. Somebody Please help